Unable to install the `tinytex` package on Windows due to incompatible `xfun` version
I am encountering an issue while trying to install the R package tinytex. After made some investigations and I guess it might due to the dependency of xfun:
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.43 is being loaded, but >= 0.48 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace


Full Logs from Console
> install.packages("tinytex")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/kevin/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘xfun’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
        binary source needs_compilation
xfun      0.43   0.49              TRUE
tinytex   0.50   0.54             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/xfun_0.43.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 483588 bytes (472 KB)
downloaded 472 KB

package ‘xfun’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp25kkFg\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘tinytex’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tinytex_0.54.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 35584 bytes (34 KB)
downloaded 34 KB

* installing *source* package 'tinytex' ...
** package 'tinytex' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.43 is being loaded, but >= 0.48 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'tinytex'
* removing 'C:/Users/kevin/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/tinytex'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/kevin/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/tinytex'

However I am unable to install xfun version 0.49 from CRAN， has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Session info
> xfun::session_info('xfun')
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044), RStudio 2024.4.2.764

Locale:
  LC_COLLATE=English_Hong Kong SAR.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Hong Kong SAR.utf8   
  LC_MONETARY=English_Hong Kong SAR.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
  LC_TIME=English_Hong Kong SAR.utf8    

Package version:
  graphics_4.2.1  grDevices_4.2.1 stats_4.2.1     tools_4.2.1     utils_4.2.1     xfun_0.43    


How can I successfully install tinytex(if possible, avoiding Rtools)? Honestly, I am not sure how to pinpoint my problem right now. My initial demand was to use pagedown to create a PDF file from markdown, but the creation failed. The render process prompted me to install tinytex, and then I try to investigate the issue following the guidance(https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging), finally I got lost in the errors....
Error: LaTeX failed to compile test.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  '"pdflatex"' not found
2: In system2(...) : '"pdflatex"' not found
Execution halted

No LaTeX installation detected (LaTeX is required to create PDF output). You should install a LaTeX distribution for your platform: https://www.latex-project.org/get/

  If you are not sure, you may install TinyTeX in R: tinytex::install_tinytex()

  Otherwise consider MiKTeX on Windows - http://miktex.org

  MacTeX on macOS - https://tug.org/mactex/
  (NOTE: Download with Safari rather than Chrome _strongly_ recommended)

  Linux: Use system package manager

My issue occurred during installation, but that problem seems to be about execution; I tried installing from CRAN, but it failed.

Thank you Limy. I guess it's somewhat different. When I tried to install tinytex, it required xfun 0.49, but I could only install version 0.43 from CRAN. It seems not quite the same?

My issue occurred during installation, but that problem seems to be about execution; I tried installing from CRAN, but it failed.

I disagree.  The error may occur at execution time, but its origin is at installation.  The link I gave you shows you how to install the latest version of xfun without relying on CRAN.  However, that may not solve your problem because "No LaTeX installation detected" suggests you have more than one issue.  Installing xfun in the way I've suggested, plus working through the corrective steps described in your error messages may help you.  It's difficult to be sure.  Even if you don't think it will work, why not try?  What have you got to lose?

yeah, I might made some beginner's mistakes thus make it messed; Anyway, I tried the method in that link, but failed. Maybe it's due my computer doesn't allow to install the Rtools? Let me add logs in the next replt.

> install.packages('xfun', repos = 'https://yihui.r-universe.dev')
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/kevin/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
  ‘xfun’
  These will not be installed


This is a not unusual situation.  You're drilling down and identifying multiple issues.  Only a few of them (eg xfun is not installed) are visible on the surface.  So, stay calm, install RTools.  Once that's been done, try to install xfun again.  Once that's been done, try to install tinytex.  Iterate until success.

thank you, I will try to apply the installation of Rtools; Another question about xfun, here is the Windows binaries version 0.49( https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xfun/index.html), but installation from CRAN cannot get that version. any steps I missed?
